# Output all text files and its regular expression match-using more than 1 regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter all txt documents in my director with multiple regular expressions, and the output to show all the files that contain any of the four regular expressions below and its match per file.

Here is what I have but I am getting errors running the code. Any ideas?

```
 import glob
    import re
    folder_path = "/home"
    file_pattern = "/*.txt"

    match_list = []

    folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

    #Search for Emails
    regex1= re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
    #Search for Phone Numbers
    regex2 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d')
    #Search for Physician's Name
    regex3=re.compile(r'\b\w\w\.\w+\b')
    #Search for SSN's
    regex4 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\

combined_pat = r'|'.join((regex1, regex2,regex3,regex4))

    for file in folder_contents:
        read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
        matches = combined_pat.findall(read_file)
        if matches:
            match_list.append(file)
            print('This file contains PHI:', file)
            print('PHI detected:', matches)
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I fixed the syntaxerror but it still is giving me another error.

Comment: what error did you get. I got lots of errors more than i expect.

Comment: EQL scanning error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a `')` on the line where you assign `regex4`. Does that fix it?